# GDB not returning useful backtraces

Tags: c++, macos, c++11, debugging, gdb

I've been writing a game engine on the side. I've been doing great progress, except anytime I need to debug anything. When I run GDB, I usually get stacktraces like this:

```
Thread 2 received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0x00007fffb73f9d42 in ?? ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007fffb73f9d42 in ?? ()
#1  0x00007fffb74e75bf in ?? ()
#2  0x00007fff5fbfafd0 in ?? ()
#3  0x000003075fbfb110 in ?? ()
#4  0x00007fff5fbfafd0 in ?? ()
#5  0x00007fffb5edbc2f in ?? ()
#6  0x00007fff5fbfafe0 in ?? ()
#7  0x00007fffb735f420 in ?? ()
#8  0xffffffff5fbfb110 in ?? ()
#9  0x0000000000000030 in ?? ()
#10 0x00007fffffffffdf in ?? ()
#11 0x00007fffc01c1a20 in ?? ()
#12 0x00007fff5fbfb100 in ?? ()
#13 0x00007fffb5eb584a in ?? ()
#14 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

Which makes it really hard to do any debugging. I'm on macOS Sierra, and this is my Makefile:

```
OUT_FILE := game

OUT_DIR := out
INC_DIR := src
SRC_DIR := src
OBJ_DIR := obj/native

C := gcc
CXX := g++
LINKER := g++
INC_DIRS := -I$(INC_DIR)
C_FLAGS = \
    -Wall \
    -D NATIVE \
    -pedantic \
    -g

CXX_FLAGS = \
    -std=c++11 \
    -std=c++14 \
    -Wall \
    -D NATIVE \
    -pedantic \
    -D DRAW_FPS \
    -D DRAW_COLLISION \
    -gdwarf \
    -g
    #-Wextra \
    #-Wshadow \

EXEC_FLAGS =
LIBS := -I /Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework/Headers -I /Library/Frameworks/SDL2_image.framework/Headers -I /Library/Frameworks/SDL2_ttf.framework/Headers -framework SDL2 -framework SDL2_image -framework SDL2_ttf

SRC_FILES := $(shell find $(SRC_DIR) -name '*.cpp' -o -name '*.c')
OBJ_FILES := $(patsubst $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp, $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o, $(SRC_FILES))
OBJ_FILES := $(patsubst $(SRC_DIR)/%.c,   $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o, $(OBJ_FILES))
DEPFILES := $(patsubst  $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp, $(OBJ_DIR)/%.d, $(SRC_FILES))
DEPFILES := $(patsubst  $(SRC_DIR)/%.c,   $(OBJ_DIR)/%.d, $(DEPFILES))

$(OUT_FILE): $(OBJ_FILES)
    $(LINKER) $(CXX_FLAGS) $(EXEC_FLAGS) $^ $(LIBS) -o $@

clean:
    rm -rf $(OBJ_DIR) $(OUT_FILE)

list:
    @echo "$(SRC_FILES)"
    @echo "$(OBJ_FILES)"

depends:
    rm -rf $(OBJ_DIR)/*.d
    $(MAKE) $(DEPFILES)

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.c
    @mkdir -p $(@D)
    $(C) $(C_FLAGS) $(INC_DIRS) -c $< -o $@

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp
    @mkdir -p $(@D)
    $(CXX) $(CXX_FLAGS) $(INC_DIRS) -c $< -o $@

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.d: $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp
    @mkdir -p $(@D)
    $(CXX) $(CXX_FLAGS) $(INC_DIRS) -MM $< | tr '\n\r\\' ' ' | sed -e 's%^%$@ %' -e 's% % $(OBJ_DIR)/%' > $@

-include $(DEPFILES)
```

Does anyone know what I'm missing?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2124/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003391-CH1-SECENABLE

Comment: 0x0000000000000000 looks like null pointer dereferencig. Maybe the stack is corrupted. Is there anything useful above that stack frame? You hav switches -g and -gdrwarf simultanously. Also you have c++14 and c++11.

Comment: No. Just gdb initializing, and a few `cout`s. I added both of those to try things out, though, to be fair, since I'm not a c++ dev by day, I wasn't sure if that would work.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to add -ggdb for more debug
2. Use valgrind to find out where you corrupt the stack. It obvious, what you corrupt some memory at stack.